# Is qnundrum dot com legit?

Tags: support

I asked this question today:

[What are the three most valuable stores in Mallcrasher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151507/)

And very shortly thereafter I found this:

http://qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=1070598

**Is this ok?**

Comment: Hm... I'd say it is, since they do give attribution, as well as a direct link to Arqade. But I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the few instances where a scraper site (that is, a site copying content off of our site) complies largely (at least as far as I can tell) with the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), particularly Section 3:

> In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content outside of the Network or Services, with the exception of content entirely created by You, You agree that You will follow the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license as follows:
>
> - You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content as coming from the Stack Exchange Network. This requirement is satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but clear visual indication.

Yep, does that. "Content on this page is from Arqade"

> - You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content includes a hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)

Yep, it does, red button under the intrusive ad.

> - You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually display or otherwise clearly indicate the author names for every question and answer so used.

Yep, it does: "Author: Steve V."

> - You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content Hyperlink each author name directly back to his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username), directly to the Stack Exchange domain, in standard HTML (i.e. not through a Tinyurl or other such indirect hyperlink, form of obfuscation or redirection), without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript disabled.

Yep, links to your profile, and to the source site. The link is also Nofollowed:
[image: link nofollowed]

That said, if you do come across a site you're suspicious about, feel free to [report it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers).

Comment: "*The link is also Nofollowed*" That doesn't seem to comply with the [SE TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal): "*...without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding detection by search engines...*"

Comment: @galacticninja Check the revision history, will ya.

Comment: This site also [misses to note](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225486/193139) that the content is licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

According to our [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) page:

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we require that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must not be nofollowed.

- It's got the visual indicator (Content on this page is from Arqade).
- It's got the hyperlink to the original question (View Full Answer on Arqade).
- It's got your name on it.
- Your name is linked back to your Arqade profile.

<strike>It still seems kinda skeezy, but it's following the attribution rules, so it looks like it's legit.</strike>

The user link is fine, but the Arqade button is nofollow'd.  Other than that single instance, it's following the rules.  But that rule is critical, so it looks like this is one of those content scraper sites that needs a Talking To by SE.

Comment: Are the link nofollow'd?

Comment: Hrm.  Missed that.

Comment: @badp the links are nofollowed (have edited this into FEichinger's answer)